# How can I chose the names for sub menus in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using the following code to create a admin menu in wordpress:

```
add_menu_page(
    "Deliverables",
    "Deliverables",
    "manage_options",
    "deliverables",
    "deliverable_create_deliverables_page"
);

add_submenu_page(
    'deliverables',
    'Review Submissions',
    'Review Submissions',
    'manage_options',
    'manage_deliverables',
    'deliverable_create_review_page'
);
```

This results in a menu that has the following structure:

```
+ Deliverables
+-- Deliverables
+-- Review Submissions
```

I.e. There will be a top level menu, and the name of the first sub menu item will be the same as the top menu name. How can I make sure I get to name all the submenu items? I would like the menu to look like this:

```
+ Deliverables
+-- Manage Deliverables
+-- Review Submissions
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by removing callback function from `add_menu_page` and placing that callback in `add_submenu_page` for top level page.

```
add_menu_page(
    "Deliverables",
    "Deliverables",
    "manage_options",
    "deliverables"
);

add_submenu_page(
    'deliverables',
    'Manage Deliverables',
    'Manage Deliverables',
    'manage_options',
    'deliverables',
    'deliverable_create_deliverables_page'
);

add_submenu_page(
    'deliverables',
    'Review Submissions',
    'Review Submissions',
    'manage_options',
    'manage_deliverables',
    'deliverable_create_review_page'
);
```

Comment: Thanks! This little thing has been bugging me for over a year I think and I have tried 1000 random things that hasn't worked... Finally I know how to do it, thanks!